# Mysqli_fetch_all no funciona

Tags: mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema, en un evento `change` para un `select`, hago una llamada a un archivo `getproducto.php` y contiene la consulta a la base de datos para llenar otro `select` y funciona de forma local en mi `xampp`, pero no me funciona en la versión del servidor, es distinta y no funciona .

Adjunto el código del archivo.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    require_once "../data/conexion.php";
    $idcat = $_POST['idcat'];
    if ($idcat != '') {
      //verificamos nuevamente que sea una opción valida
      /*Obtenemos los discos de la banda seleccionada*/
      $sql = "SELECT  id_producto, concat_ws(' ', name, modelo) as prod from productos where id_categoria = '$idcat' order by name";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
<option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
<?php foreach ($filas as $op):  ?>
  <option value="<?=$op['id_producto']?>"><?=$op['prod']?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>

/*Como puedo reemplazar el mysqli_fetch_all*/
```

Comment: Perdon siempre tengo problemas para adjuntar el codigo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones, ya que mysqli_fetch_all no está disponible en tu servidor por que no compiló mysqlnd :

Puedes crear un loop:

```
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row; }
```

Puedes crear una compatibilidad manualmente, así no tienes que modificar tu código.

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
function mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_result $result) {
    $data = [];
    while ($data[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}
    return $data;
}
```

Como opción plus puedes hacer que tu servidor compile mysqlnd pero quizás es mas tedioso.
Espero te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono con el bucle while